# Date Format (dd M yyyy) in Spring Freemarker(.ftl)

Tags: jquery, spring, date

I have a dropdown and i need to display cid-date(in dd M yyyy) format in spring freemarker(.ftl file).
My dropdown code...

```
        <td>:&#160;&#160;
                <select id="appshift" name="shift" onchange="doFetch()">
                    <option value="">-select-</option>
                        <#list extshiftcode as shiftList>
                    <option value="${shiftList.cid}">${shiftList.cid} -${shiftList.fromDate} </option>
                    </#list>        
                </select>
            </td>
```

Can any one please suggest me how to display Date in  dd M yyyy this format.
I am using also using Jquery,if any idea to using jquery to make date format change in .ftl file.

please Suggest me.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<option value="${shiftList.cid}">${shiftList.cid} -${shiftList.fromDate?string("dd M yyyy")} </option>` if *shiftList.fromDate* is a **Date**.